# How to add appended text next to an output?

Tags: c#

I have made a trackbar that adjusts the oven temperature accordingly and displays the value in a textbox. I then on the click of a button, the value is displayed in another textbox which works fine. I am trying to have the same statement always appear in front of whatever the value is to give it context. This is what I have tried however the Oven Temp value appears but nothing else. Any help would be much appreciated :)

```
        Feeback.AppendText("Oven Temperature = ");
        Feeback.Text = Oven_Temp.Text;
```

Comment: `Feeback.Text = "Oven Temperature = " + Oven_Temp.Text;`?

Comment: For what it's worth, this is called String Concaternation. There's lots of ways to do it. If you search that term you'll find lots of examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to follow up on what @WSC said and why it worked.

```
1| Feeback.AppendText("Oven Temperature = ");
2| Feeback.Text = Oven_Temp.Text;
```

Line 1 - this will append `Oven Temperature =` to the existing text in `Feedback.Text`.

Line 2 - this is, subsequently, *overwriting* whatever is in `Feedback.Text`

So, you were only seeing the oven temperature because line 2 was overwriting whatever you did in line 1.

As @WSC correctly pointed out, you can do it by joining the two items together using "string concatenation" and (as @WSC also said!) there are many, many ways to do this, each with pros and cons when you get into a higher performance application.

```
Feedback.Text = "Oven Temperature = " + Oven_Temp.Text;
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. As you mentioned there are pros and cons. I have done this as I am creating a UI control panel but use a multi line textbox to output diagnostic characteristics, will this cause issues down the line when multiple events are happening and displaying the list of outputs?

Comment: @RAG - that's a very tricky question to answer.  I'm not sure if you're asking about performance of string concatenation or if having multiple events updating the same field will cause issues.  For the former, (and this is just my opinion) I would say that if I was building up a string made up of more than 3-4 parts, then I would use a `StringBuilder` to build the string before setting the value of the textbox.  If you're asking about multiple events updating the same textbox then I would suggest reading up on multithreading and the `lock` statement in C# to try and have control over that.